Logrotate for freeradius accounting logs
I have this config for log detail:
/opt/freeradius/logs/*/detail {

daily
rotate 4
compress
delaycompress
missingok
notifempty
create 0640 root root
sharedscripts
maxsize 500M
postrotate
    /bin/systemctl reload freeradius > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
endscript
}

I have these olds logs with new logs :
[root@freeradius01 192.168.17.10]# pwd
/opt/freeradius/logs/192.168.17.10
[root@freeradius01 192.168.17.10]# ll
total 56919724
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21048752215 Aug 14 23:59 detail-20240814
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21617187765 Aug 15 23:59 detail-20240815
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  5988044800 Aug 16 23:59 detail-20240816
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     5947392 Sep 25 23:59 detail-20240925
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  7478423552 Oct 21 23:59 detail-20241021
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1907452140 Oct 22 11:19 detail-20241022
[root@freeradius01 192.168.17.10]#

When running logrotate manually and forced with verbos I have this result:
[root@freeradius01 192.168.17.10]#  /usr/sbin/logrotate -v -f /etc/logrotate.d/radiusd
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/radiusd
Reading state from file: /var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status
Allocating hash table for state file, size 64 entries
Creating new state
Creating new state
Creating new state
..
..
Creating new state

Handling logs


rotating pattern: /opt/freeradius/logs/*/detail  forced from command line (4 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, log files >= 524288000 are rotated earlier, old logs are removed
considering log /opt/freeradius/logs/*/detail
not running postrotate script, since no logs were rotated


[root@freeradius01 192.168.17.10]# ll
total 56919724
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21048752215 Aug 14 23:59 detail-20240814
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21617187765 Aug 15 23:59 detail-20240815
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  5988044800 Aug 16 23:59 detail-20240816
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     5947392 Sep 25 23:59 detail-20240925
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  7478423552 Oct 21 23:59 detail-20241021
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1968389637 Oct 22 11:22 detail-20241022
[root@freeradius01 192.168.17.10]# grep "detail"   /var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status
"/var/log/radius/radacct/*/detail" 2024-3-5-3:0:0
"/opt/freeradius/logs/*/detail" 2024-3-5-3:0:0
[root@freeradius01 192.168.17.10]# date
Tue Oct 22 11:22:45 WAT 2024
[root@freeradius01 192.168.17.10]#

So the log rotation not running despite I runned it manually / also old logs not compressed!!?

When the rule's pattern, /opt/freeradius/logs/*/detail, does not match any of the log files in a directory, logrotate does nothing. You would need to create a dummy detail file in directory /opt/freeradius/logs/192.168.17.10/ before trying to force the logrotate in this situation. But you would also need to remove notifempty temporarily from the config, and also not do it on the same day as the date extention -20241022 that already exists, or logrotate will abort as the file already exists.
